# Mongoose find() returns an empty doc

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

why does this function return an empty document? There is an other function that uses find({}) without any query and it works.

```
router.get('/mesCandidatures/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    Models.Candidature.find({"figurant":req.params.id}, function(err,docs) {
        if (err){
            throw err;
        }else{
            res.send(docs);
        }
    });
});
```

I send this parameter: 59e5d09f853d00049fd67600

I am supposed to receive this:

```
{ 
"_id":"59ea0d1fea79bf099696fcab",
"etat":"validé",
"figurant":"59e5d09f853d00049fd67600",
"offre":"59e5bc1438950e01ae45d1d2"
}`
```

Thanks

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Which means, if you get an empty result then we need to also see: 1. The request parameter being sent. 2. The document you believe should match. Also read the help center link. In order for your case to "reproduce" you should be able to see if there are any current problems, i.e Input not what you expect or data not what you expect.

Comment: sorry! i've added more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem might be caused by filtering with an incorrect field type `figurant`

Your `req.params.id` is a string, while i am guessing that `figurant` is defined in your schema as type `ObjectId`, so you need to filter by `ObjectId` not a `string`

Change your code to be :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
router.get('/mesCandidatures/:id', function(req, res, next) {
        Models.Candidature.find({"figurant":mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)}, function(err,docs) {
         if (err){
             throw err;
         }else{
             res.send(docs);
         }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have in your code is an instance of Query returned in a callback, so in case of `find()` you have to use `exec()` for mongoose to know when it has to be executed, so your request should be

```
router.get('/mesCandidatures/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    Models.Candidature.find({ figurant: req.params.id }).exec( function(err,docs) {
        if (err){
            throw err;
        }else{
            res.send(docs);
        }
    });
});
```

But originally you use `find()` when you need to get a list of a documents, if you need a single document you can use `findOne()` that instead of query returns you a potentially-null single document. Then you can get your callback as you did:

```
router.get('/mesCandidatures/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    Models.Candidature.findOne({ figurant: req.params.id }, function(err,docs) {
        if (err){
            throw err;
        }else{
            res.send(docs);
        }
    });
});
```

Also, you don't have to use a quotes for your condition unless you are not getting nested fields with paths like `"nested.field"`